# I'd like to display a string with location, date & time (of a pre-set timezone)

Tags: javascript, date

What I'd like to achieve should look like [this](http://soke.studio/info.html) in the bottom corner. However, I'd like to set a timezone, e.g. New York (that's not a timezone I know lol, but you understand) and it should display 'New York April 1st 05:42'.

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: Use https://momentjs.com/.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one post. Also, you should make **some** attempt at writing your own code. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @RobG I'm 17 and have 0 experience with Javascript. I know Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service but I can't just learn it in a day and I'd like to have it for school. I was hoping there'd be someone nice to help me out.

Comment: @mxainz You can use moment.js as Nicolae mentioned to set timezones otherwise I dont think you can set timezone in plain javascript Date object

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

setInterval(function(){ 
    var now = new Date();
    var time = monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getDate() + ", " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = time; 
  }, 1000);
  
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone + ", ";
```

```html
<p id="time"><span id="name"></span> <span id="currentTime"></span></p>
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar What does he mean?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar np thank you as well

Comment: That's almost what I want! Now it is displaying the timezone I am in, but I'd like it to always display GMT+5

Comment: @mxainz I dont think you can do this using javascript

Answer (score 1):

```js
// get a new date (locale machine date time)
var date = new Date();

// First converting to UTC and then adding +360 to make it +5 GMT 
const millisecondsOffset = ((date.getTimezoneOffset() + 360 ) * 60 * 1000);
date.setTime(date.getTime() - millisecondsOffset);

// get the date as a string
var n = date.toDateString();
// get the time as a string
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();

// find the html element with the id of time
// set the innerHTML of that element to the date a space the time
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'Islamabad, Karachi'+ ' ' + n + ' ' + time;
```

```html
<div id='time'></div>
```

Comment: That's almost what I want! Now it is displaying the timezone I am in, but I'd like it to always display GMT+5

Comment: Updated, You can hard code the timezone string and I have adjusted the time accordingly.

Comment: this is amazing, thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: You are correct if he want a specific timezone he can just write it down. Good one.

Comment: @mxainz If this solved you problem, you mark it as an accepted answer, by clicking on the tick arrow below the answer. :)